# On iOS, why the init in ViewController didn't work?

Tags: ios

In the ViewController's interface, I have

```
@property int count;
```

and in the implementation, I have

```
@synthesize count;

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.count = 100;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"%i", self.count++);
}
```

but for some reason, the first time `self.count` got printed, it is 0 but not 100?

Comment: how is the view controller getting created?

Comment: it is a standard Single View app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of various -init methods will be called on your UIViewController, depending on whether it came out of a .xib, storyboard, or is alloc'd manually somewhere else in your code.

A better place to put this kind of initialization is in -viewDidLoad, something like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.count = 100;
}
```

Comment: so this is not a pattern that we put all the init code in our own `init` method huh?

Comment: I often find it cleaner to use -viewDidLoad because then you don't have to worry about how the ViewController is initialized.  Otherwise, you have to cover -initWithCoder, -intiWithNibName:bundle, and just plain -init (possibly others)

Answer (score 1):

Put a NSLog or debugging breakpoint in your init method and I suspect you'll find it isn't called. If you look at UIViewController, you'll see other initialization methods (e.g. if you're using a NIB, it would invoke [`initWithNibName:bundle:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a)). If it's via a storyboard, it can differ. See the discussion of initialization in Apple's [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW6).

A better place for general view controller configuration is `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: are you certain about `initWithNibName`?  I added that method and it didn't initialize count... but I didn't define any parameter for the method

Comment: My point is that there are a whole bunch of init methods. Unless you're calling it yourself (e.g. this view controller is one that one of your other views initializes, allocs and opens), you better not try to guess which one is being used. Do you sundry initializations in `viewDidLoad`, not any particular init method.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.count = 100;
    }
    return self;
}
```

The view is actually getting created by the XIB, which is 'decoding' it or unboxing it. When this happens, the XIB calls `initWithCoder:`

Comment: can you double check... i tried setting it to 10000 and removed the one in viewDidLoad but it didn't get set to 10000